# can't search text in tag a with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

i cerate javascript for search tag a in accordion

```
function search(){
  let filter = document.getElementById('find').value.toUpperCase();
  let item = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
  let l = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  
  for(let i = 0; i<=l.length;i++){
      let a= item[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
      let value=a.innerHTML || a.innerText || a.textContent;
      if(value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
        item[i].style.display = "";
      } else{
        item[i].style.display = "none";
      }    
    }
}
```

With bootstrap 5.2, I created an accordion in the following HTML. I attempt to make a condition search box using js, but it is not searchable.

```
<!-- search start -->
<div class="container text-center">
    <form class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 ps-4 ">
            <label for="inputvideo" class="visually-hidden ">sreach</label>
            <input type="text" id="find" class="form-control mb-3" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="search()"placeholder="sreach">
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- search end -->

<p>category :</p>
<div class="accordion accordion-flush pb-3" id="accordionFlushExample">

<!-- advice start  -->
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">advice
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark ms-3" id="test"onclick="light(1)">1.appication</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- advice end-->
</div>
```

i want to search text in a tag

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console, possibly about using `item[i] `? That item is probably a list of 1 accordion, while i is an index for a link

Comment: i not found error my console

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample has couple of issues if you are considering each `<a>` tag inside the accordion class to filtered based on input text.

Below code seems like buggy in your case:

```
for(let i = 0; i<=l.length;i++){
  let a= item[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  let value=a.innerHTML || a.innerText || a.textContent;
```

Try this and see if this suits your need:

```js
function search() {
  let filter = document.getElementById("find").value.toUpperCase();
  let item = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
  let l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    let a = item[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log("a[i]: ", a[i]);
    let value = a[i].innerHTML || a[i].innerText || a[i].textContent;
    if (value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      item[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      item[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- search start -->
<div class="container text-center">
  <form class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-12 ps-4 ">
      <label for="inputvideo" class="visually-hidden ">sreach</label>
      <input type="text" id="find" class="form-control mb-3" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="sreach">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- search end -->

<p>category :</p>
<div class="accordion accordion-flush pb-3" id="accordionFlushExample">

  <!-- advice start  -->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">advice
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark ms-3" id="test" onclick="light(1)">1.application</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- advice end-->
</div>
```

Comment: When I type a search, the accordion class vanishes, and the search results are not displayed.

Comment: @Nwp_ What are you typing into the search box, and what are your expectations? If you're typing `advice`, instead of `application`, it's supposed to work like that - `advice` is not within `a` text, and since there are no `a` elements with text matching `advice`, it gets hidden . Your original code is only matching based on the `a` text.